# RMarkdown Knit HTML using global environment objects

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Say I have `testdata <- 1` in the global environment in RStudio
I want to call testdata in a .rmd file I'd like to knit within RStudio.

````
```{r}
print(testdata)
```
````

How can I achieve this?

It seems using rmarkdown::render() can do the job. However I cant. When I call print() it returns me a chunk of code starts like:

```
## function (..., list = character(), package = NULL, lib.loc = NULL, 
##     verbose = getOption("verbose"), envir = .GlobalEnv) 
## {
##     fileExt <- function(x) {
##         db <- grepl("\\.[^.]+\\.(gz|bz2|xz)$", x)
##         ans <- sub(".*\\.", "", x)
##         ans[db] <- sub(".*\\.([^.]+\\.)(gz|bz2|xz)$", "\\1\\2", 
##             x[db])
##         ans
##     }
```

Comment: The output looks like the first few lines from `utils::data()`. Let me guess: In your `Rmd` file, you wrote `data` instead of `testdata`?

Comment: @user2706569 nice guess. The cause is no smarter than that, if not sillier: I did not save the RMD file after I modified it and before I ran it.